# How could I only include classes and functions docstring instead of module docstring when using Sphinx?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring, autodoc

Let's say I have a python module like below:

test.py:

```
__doc__ = """This is the module docstring."""

class ClassA:
    """This is ClassA's docstring"""
    pass

def func():
    """This is a test function"""
    pass
```

I want to display the module docstring and its class and function docstring in different pages using Sphinx. Here is what I did:

In `module_doc.rst`:

```
Doc
====

.. automodule:: test
    :special-members: __doc__
```

In `usage_doc.rst`:

```
Usage
======

.. automodule:: test
    :members:
```

In `Doc` page, it show only the content of `__doc__` as expected. But in `Usage` page, the `__doc__` content is also displayed above the docstring of class and function, which is not my intention.

Is there any method to solve my problem?